# Magento : How to Create Recent Orders Block on CMS Page or Static Block

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, blocks

Which code should be used to create `Recent Orders Block`; like on the customer dashboard; on CMS page or Static Block; I would like to put this on the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below template in cms

```
{{block type="sales/order_recent" template="sales/order/recent.phtml"}}
```

Give permission to `sales/order_recent` Block from admin

> System -> Permission -> Block -> Add New Block (Button)